# How to keep a formula but resolve range(s) in it to their values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Suppose I have a cell A1. So suppose I do something like

`let formula = sheet.getRange("A1").cash_sales_col.getFormula()`

this makes the formula variable store "=B1+12+14-50+D1" (assuming the range A1 cell had this formula).

I would like to keep the breakup but resolve the cells in the formula to values.

E.g. if B1 is 1200 and D1 is 20. I want to get the result of the above formula as the string "=1200+12+14-50+20".

using .getValue() will return the full result of the computation but not the breakup.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without parsing the formula manually?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `let formula = sheet.getRange("A1").cash_sales_col.getFormula()` and `this makes the formula variable store "=B1+12+14-50+D1" (assuming the range A1 cell had this formula).` and `I would like to keep the breakup but resolve the cells in the formula to values.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the images?

Comment: OK I will give other example.

With sheet setup like this [link] (https://imgur.com/a/txkIoHE)

If I run code `Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").getFormula());` I get output "=A1+A2".  If I run code `Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C2").getValue());` I get output "36"
But I want to keep formula but expand value.  So I want result  "=12+24"

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I understood your goal is as follows. You want to replace A1Notation with the number. If my understanding is correct, I think that when the formula is simple like your sample, this can be easily achieved. But, if the formula is complicated, achieving your goal might be difficult. I'm worried about this. So, can I ask you about your actual formula?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. My formula is variable. But will only contain "+,-,/,* and ()". e.g. "=A1+B1+40-200+(200-20)+12*2". OR "=B1+1800-14-20+C1" etc.

Comment: Tanaike do you know if there is a way to break the formula into parts and separate the A1 notation from the rest. Then get the values of those ranges and then do string substitution back into the original formula?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample formulas of `My formula is variable. But will only contain "+,-,/,* and ()". e.g. "=A1+B1+40-200+(200-20)+12*2". OR "=B1+1800-14-20+C1" etc.` and your script of `getRange("C2").getValue()`, in your situation, where are the formulas? For example, those are "C2:C" or only "C2"?

Comment: getRange("C2").getValue() will hold the formula. I may have to do the same thing for one or 2 more individual cells. E.g.  getRange("C2").getValue() may have formula "=A1+40+B1" AND   getRange("D1").getValue() may have formula "=C1+E1". I would like to convert A1 notation for these cells. E.g. a function convertCellA1Notation (formualCell) and then calling this function on 1 or more known cells. E.g. convertCellA1Notation ("C2") & convertCellA1Notation("D1").

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `E.g. convertCellA1Notation ("C2") & convertCellA1Notation("D1")`, in your goal, what value do you want to return at your function of `convertCellA1Notation`? So, how will you do the function `convertCellA1Notation`? For example, when you want to use this as a custom function, the formula cannot be returned as a formula. So, I would like to confirm it before I posted an answer. I apologize that I try to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. It will not handle any complex formula's e.g. sum(A1:B2) etc. But it works for my simple use case. E.g. using the cell as a basic calculator. Posting here in case it is helpful to others.

```
function convertCellFormulaA1Notation (range) {
  const regex = /((?:[A-Za-z]+)?\d+|[=*()+-/])/g;
  const A1NotationRegex = /^[A-Za-z]/; 
  const formula = range.getFormula();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  console.log(formula);
  const formula_components = formula.match(regex)
  let expanded_formula = [];


  for (let x of formula_components) {
    if (A1NotationRegex.test(x) === true) {
      expanded_formula.push(sheet.getRange(x).getValue())
    } else {
      expanded_formula.push(x)
    }
  }

  const result = expanded_formula.join('');
  //console.log("Result: "+ result);
  return result;

}
```

usage:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
range = sheet.getRange("A1");
console.log(convertCellFormulaA1Notation(range));
```